# Prevent floats from creating new line

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know this question has been asked before ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10298520/1366033), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266015/1366033), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10248306/1366033), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9492542/1366033), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9672176/1366033), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10891293/1366033)), but none of these solutions seem to be working for me.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/5dEdRvCs.png" />
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper > *{
    float: left;
}
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/LgJ4w/)

---

I'd like both the `img` and the `div` under the wrapper to `float` `left`, and for the div with all the text to take up all the remaining space on the page, like this:

[image: demo-good]

Instead it looks like this:

[image: demo-bad]

---

I've tried adding `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper, tried a number of `width` and `min-width` settings, but to no avail.

There must be some relatively simple way in CSS to accomplish this.

Comment: Something is wrong with your images: they're gone.

Comment: I feel that this has some relevance. See **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941804/vertically-align-text-right-of-floated-image-image-sizes-varied-responsive)**, then see my answer below it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just float the image, and the text will align to the right.

```
.wrapper img {
    float:left;
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/LgJ4w/15/).

Comment: I like it, although is it possible for it to not [wrap below the image](http://i.imgur.com/quDptRz.png)?

Comment: If you want it for wrap below the image then you can use this code but you need to put your image inside the div area.

Comment: @KyleMit to prevent the text wrapping after the image, give the text a left margin equivalent to the width of the image. Of course this only works if all your images are the same width.
http://jsfiddle.net/LgJ4w/17/

Comment: @MarkSimpson, perfect.  You link didn't have the left margin set so i created this one: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/LgJ4w/18/

Comment: @KyleMit Yeah i forgot to update the fiddle before posting it here. Have updated my comment.

Comment: For that, you could set widths for both as Adil mentioned.  You could also float one left, and one right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually bringing every element to left. So the image is left and the text is also in the left.

If you put a width on both image and text that will work for you.

You can try with :

```
.wrapper img {
    width: 20%;
}
.wrapper > div {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Then it will work as you wanted.

Comment: Except the `img` should not be a variable width, but hold it's width at all page sizes.

Comment: I use the variable width to keep the work responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`

Here is the fiddle:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug8e5/)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it has issues with [smaller widths](http://i.imgur.com/tRdMI6i.png)